# Cleaning text files and importing as pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time-series file with a header and meteorological data, like this:

"NAME: Timeseries results

LOC_I: 130

LOC_J: 181

LAT: -9.03

LON: -35.22

UNITS: SECONDS

SECONDS YY MM DD hh mm ss wind_x wind_y hourly_prec rel_hum

|BeginResults|

0 2007 1 1 0 0 0 1.2 0.5 0 97.5

3600 2007 1 1 1 0 0 2.3 0.7 0 97.6

7200 2007 1 1 2 0 0 2.6 0.7 0 97.5

10800 2007 1 1 3 0 0 1.9 0.6 0 97.4

...

|EndResults|"

And I need to import the numerical data as a pandas dataframe with the information from row [6] as columns, so I have to delete rows [0:5], [7] and [-1] but I'm not having success with handling this in a simple python code, could you help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It certainly helps when you post what you already tried and why or where the code failed. Spoken about code: you can format it in your post with ctrl-k to enhance readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("/path/to/file", 
            sep=" ",
            header=6,
            skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
            engine="python",
            skipfooter=1)
```

`sep` makes it split the columns using a space as a delimiter. Based on the documentation, looks like this can also take a regular expression, but I've never tried that.

`header` makes the dataframe use row 6 (0-indexed) as the column names.

`skiprows` tells pandas which rows you want it to skip. Instead of a list of row indices, you can also give it an int (number of rows from start to skip) or a callable (if it evaluates to True, it skips that row). More detailed info in the linked docs if you need it.

`engine` determines which engine it uses. This is needed because `skipfooter` is only supported on the python engine.

`skipfooter` tells it how many lines you want to skip from the bottom.

The full documentation for `read_csv()` is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), and it's pretty thorough, if you need to add any more constrictions to the parsing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly! Just made some adjustment because when you set the header row pandas already skip rows above, so the code is just:

pd.read_csv("/path/to/file", 
            sep=" ",
            header=6,
            skiprows=[7],
            engine="python",
            skipfooter=1)

Tks a lot again :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided you only want to remove first N rows, why not just import the whole csv ( was it a csv?) as a DataFrame and then drop first N, or reassign rows you want to keep to a new DataFrame , filtering with iloc property? like:

```
In [21]: df                       
Out[21]: 
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11

In [24]: df1 = df.iloc[1:,:]      

In [25]: df1                      
Out[25]: 
   A  B   C   D
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
```

Comment: The question states that they also need to remove the last row and row 7, while using row 6 for the column headers. This approach could still work of course, but you'd need a bit extra to set the column names

Comment: you're right, I missed that part of the headers on the 6th row, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

str_data = """"NAME: Timeseries results

LOC_I: 130

LOC_J: 181

LAT: -9.03

LON: -35.22

UNITS: SECONDS

SECONDS YY MM DD hh mm ss wind_x wind_y hourly_prec rel_hum

|BeginResults|

0 2007 1 1 0 0 0 1.2 0.5 0 97.5

3600 2007 1 1 1 0 0 2.3 0.7 0 97.6

7200 2007 1 1 2 0 0 2.6 0.7 0 97.5

10800 2007 1 1 3 0 0 1.9 0.6 0 97.4

|EndResults|"""

text = os.linesep.join([s for s in str_data.splitlines() if s])
list_data = text.split('\n')
weather_data_header = list_data[6].split()
weather_data = [row.split() for row in list_data[8:len(list_data)-1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(weather_data, columns=weather_data_header)
df.head()
```